# Mobile UI that works well for both iPhone and Blackberry Web Applications

Tags: iphone, blackberry, frameworks, mobile-website

Can someone recommend a good Mobile UI Javascript/jQuery framework that works well with both the iPhone and Blackberry?  I'm developing the core app from ASP.NET.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is today, the BlackBerry browser is not very friendly to these libraries.  But the upcoming version will support HTML 5, which will allow you to use most popular js frameworks.  From personal experience I can recommend Sencha and jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any personal experience with any of these, but I thought I'd mention a few that I've heard of.  It will probably depend more on the features you require for your specific application, to determine which framework suits you best.  Also, this is by no means an exhaustive list - the "cross-platform" mobile frameworks seem to be popping up all over the place recently!

- [Rhodoes](http://rhomobile.com/)
- [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)
- [ramp](http://ramp.virtualmobiletech.com/)
- [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Sencha Touch or Sproutcore.

Sencha Touch is very similar to EXTJS, which a lot of front end developers really like.  Check out

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

It is probably more mature than SC, and you will have a larger developer base on which to draw.  You are gonna wanna try out the demos on that link, on a phone or ipad if you have one.

However, I personally like the strong MVC pattern that Sproutcore enforces.  The mobile framework exists, but I don't know of any major clients adopting it, yet.  The founder of SC, Charles Jolley, recently left Apple to push his framework; its gonna be big.

Comment: Sencha is the combination of Ext JS, jQTouch and Raphaël javascript projects from a company perspective. The RIM browser won't support any web app today because it's not really a modern browser, but they have promised a proper WebKit browser in their new phones out later this year.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry has very basic browser.

But for iPhone, you can try  [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/). Its lightweight and amazing.